# How can I convert DSD file formats to FLAC, WAV, (etc) with Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, flac, dsd

I've recently started getting into more higher end HiFi, and found some downloads which are only available to buy in DSD format. (No FLAC available.)

Can I convert to/from DSD formats to FLAC using some kind of Linux command line facility?

I know nothing about DSD - it is something I am totally new to.

Comment: ffmpeg seems to have dsd decoder

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg -i input.dsf -c:a flac output.flac` should work fine

`ffmpeg -i input.dsf -c:a flac -af "lowpass=24000, volume=6dB" -sample_fmt s16 -ar 48000 output.flac` to avoid distorsion in the upper frequency range.

Answer (score 0):

You can make conversion, but if your DAC supports DSD it's better to play DSD file as it is. In linux mpd configured with alsa works great with DSD files, so I personally play native DSD without any conversion. Conversion is not bad thing, but if unnecessary I would avoid it. There is also dop option (in MPD), if your DAC doesn't support native DSD, in this case DSD is converted into PCM.

Comment: `in this case DSD is converted into PCM` more like masqueraded as. DoP still requires DAC support for demodulating DSD. It's really just a different way to transceive DSD.